# Uploading Angular application to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, iis

I have an Angular front end application created with VS Code and a backend Web API application running of .NET Framework created in Visual Studio.

I am now trying to deploy both applications to IIS but am having some trouble getting the backend to deploy properly. As the front end and back end are two separate projects how do i go about achieving the deployment properly.

I currently have the Angular front end displaying on IIS. I achieved this by copying the contents of the dist folder to a identifiable location then in IIS, I added a website where the physcial path points to the location of the dist folder.

My attempt to get the back end working was to copy the content of the publish folder to an identifiable location, then create an unmanaged pool for hosting the asp.net app. I then added an application to the previously created website and pointed to the folder that held my published back end code.

I then restarted the website, when browsing the site all I see is the front end, there is no connections being made to the back end. I get some errors in the console.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any further details

Comment: try publishing the backend using this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis#publish-to-iis

Comment: Can you specify which version of .NET framework is used. If you can upgrade your application to versions greater than .NET CORE 2.1, you'll have the option to use a default template with angular as mentioned in the below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: So i can access my application through IIS locally on the server but not through the public IP

Comment: Make sure your firewall is not blocking site bonded port(81) from public access. You may not be able to use loop-back, so try accessing from a computer outside your intranet (at the office or at a friend's), or use a proxy. which identity did you set for your application pool?

Comment: I think the problem is that in my angular app all the request are being sent to http://localhost:54946/api/{controller}  does this need to be changed and if so what to

Comment: please check your code or try to use the application like fiddler to capture request.